# Second application and passport with myself?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, applications

We want to apply for a second visitor visa application while some time is remaining on the previous 6 month visitor visa.

At the point we want to apply can we travel also to uk during that period and keep the passport with ourself or is it important to submit passport ?? Because without a passport one cannot travel to UK?

Comment: Some countries, like the US, let you apply for a second passport if one must submit one for a visa but also travel during the period the visa is being processed. But you'd need to do it well ahead of time so you can submit the new passport for the new visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are applying in a location where the ‘Keep My Passport When Applying’ service is available. After enrolling your biometrics and submitting your visa application, this allows you to keep your passport until the UK embassy makes a decision regarding your visa, one way or the other.
Once the decision is made, you will be called once again to complete the procedures as required by the embassy.

https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/article-uk-visa-guide.html